# What's meaning of the `c` in `crw-rw-rw-` in linux file permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions

I run the command: `ll /dev/null` and got this output:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Feb 19 10:20 /dev/null
```

I know `d` means directory. Can someone please explain what the `c` special flag means?

Comment: Character soecial file (a device).

Answer (score 25):

It's a character device based file
Within Linux devices such as hardware are characterised in two ways:

- Character Devices (c) which are devices which transfer data in characters also known as bytes or bits such as mice, speaker etc.
- Block Devices (b) which are devices which transfer data in blocks of data such as USB, Hard Disks etc.

These types of files can commonly be found within the /dev directory which is where device files are stored, just type **ls -lah** and you can see the various types.

If you're running a decent Linux distro, that information (plus more than you could probably ever need) can be obtained with the command:

```
info ls
```

which contains this little snippet:

---

```
The file type is one of the following characters:
    -  regular file
    b  block special file
    c  character special file
    C  high performance ("contiguous data") file
    d  directory
    D  door (Solaris 2.5 and up)
    l  symbolic link
    M  off-line ("migrated") file (Cray DMF)
    n  network special file (HP-UX)
    p  FIFO (named pipe)
    P  port (Solaris 10 and up)
    s  socket
    ?  some other file type
```

Answer (score 3):

It is 'character oriented device' is this case  (b means block oriented device)...
That's why /dev/null in your example is so efficient in redirections for example with

```
command 2> /dev/null
```

In fact it is not a permission but a "definition mark"