# meaning of file type c in ls -l command

Tags: files, ls, file-descriptors

I am wondering what the type c is in the ls command.

I was following the symlinks at /dev/stdin and ended up with /dev/pts/0

```
$ ls -l /dev/pts/0
crw--w---- 1 blue tty 136, 0 Apr  8 21:50 /dev/pts/0
```

I can see the first symbol in the mode output is a `c`. Now I am trying to find out what this means.

I could find some information but c is not listed and some of them seem also a bit wrong. At least on my box a symlink has a lowercase l, not an uppercase L.

```
d      if the entry is a directory;
a      if the entry is an append-only file;
D      if the entry is a Unix device;
L      if the entry is a symbolic link;
P      if the entry is a named pipe;
S      if the entry is a socket;
-      if the entry is a plain file.
```

source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/ls.1plan9.html

I can read in `man pts` that these are pseudo terminal master slave pairs.

> ptmx, pts - pseudoterminal master and slave
> When a process opens /dev/ptmx, it gets a file descriptor for a pseudoterminal master and a pseudoterminal slave device is created in the /dev/pts  directory.   Each  file  descriptor  obtained  by  opening  /dev/ptmx  is an independent pseudoterminal master with its own associated slave, whose path can be found by passing the file descriptor to ptsname(3).

So what does the `c` stand for? I assume it means this is a `pseudoterminal slave device`.

Edit:

After reading and thinking more about it, I guess its `c` because its essentially a *console*.

Comment: If you are not running Plan9, a Plan9 manual that you've found on the web won't be of much help.  Instead, see `man ls` on your own system.

Comment: @Kusalananda `man ls` on my system doesnt say anything about that at all. It has no description of the different types.

Comment: If it's not in the manual, then the manual might have a "SEE ALSO" section. In any case, the answer is [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568569/whats-meaning-of-the-c-in-crw-rw-rw-in-linux-file-permissions/568573#568573)

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes thank you. The ALSO section had a link to a webpage and that one had another link where is described https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html

Comment: Ah, so you're on a GNU system. Yeah, they tend to spread their documentation out in various places, for better and for worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"c" indicates that the device is a "character special device".  If you look in `/dev` you will also see "b" for "block special device", for instance all of your disks.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Character_devices).

Device files allow direct access to the device drivers.  Historically UNIX would provide bothe a character and block device for block structured devices such as disks.  The "c" device allows direct access to the device without going through system buffers.  The name is a bit misleading, "raw" would be a better one, but history dictates "c".  For a terminal this allows outputting or inputting one or more characters at a time.  For a disk though it will not allow a byte level access, the caller must ensure that all block alignment and addressing is done by the caller.  "b" devices might be better termed "buffered" devices.  The I/O is done to the system's buffers and at a point decided by the system is moved to disk.  Due to the buffereing it is possible that the device driver will accept non-aligned blocks of varying size.

Answer (score 2):

The first character identifies the file type:

```
-    Regular file
b    Block special file
c    Character special file
d    Directory
l    Symbolic link
n    Network file
p    FIFO
s    Socket
```

For a regular file the '-' may be replaced by:

```
D    Demand recall file
E    Encrypted file
O    Offline file
S    Sparse file
```

Comment: See also [How many possible file types in the output \`ls -l\` command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/538419)